# Removing/Re-adding filter options

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I already have functionality to initially hide rows containing deprecated information and subsequently allow toggling of showing/hiding these rows. I want the options in the filters to reflect what rows are currently displayed in the table, since there are more deprecated options to filter by than non-deprecated ones.

Non-tablesorter implementation that works:
http://jsfiddle.net/X6EBS/1/

My tablesorter code where I tried the above implementation and failed:
http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3534/

I have come across the

```
select_filterSource
```

option, but frankly I don't understand how to use it to do what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things need to be modified:

1. Add "tablesorter-infoOnly" class name to the hidden tbody

   ```
   <tbody id="hide" class="tablesorter-infoOnly" style="display:none;"></tbody>
   ```
2. Add "filter-onlyAvail" to the first header

   ```
   <th class="filter-select filter-onlyAvail">AlphaNumeric</th>
   ```

Here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3535/).

Comment: Thanks so much, that's perfect! Why do you only need to add the `filter-onlyAvail` class to the first header and not each one with a filter on it?

Comment: Actually after playing with it a bit more, I think I just want to stick with the first modification, that's all I need. Thanks again!